# PYNQ-Z1 : How to stream a video from HDMI input to HDMI output using base overlay?

Tags: python, video-streaming, xilinx, hdmi, zynq

I'm trying to capture a video from HDMI input of PYNQ-Z1 board and stream it to HDMI output using inbuilt base overlay. Below is the code I'm using:

```
from pynq.overlays.base import BaseOverlay
from pynq.lib.video import *
base = BaseOverlay("base.bit")
hdmi_in = base.video.hdmi_in
hdmi_out = base.video.hdmi_out
hdmi_in.configure()
hdmi_out.configure(hdmi_in.mode)
hdmi_in.start()
hdmi_out.start()
hdmi_in.tie(hdmi_out)
```

Running the code doesn't throw any error, but still I can't see any video being displayed to the monitor connected to HDMI out of PYNQ-Z1. The monitor is turning on and off periodically, and saying : "No Data". I checked the monitor by connecting directly to a laptop and played a video. Then the monitor display works perfectly. But whenever I'm trying to route the video through PYNQ-Z1, it is not working.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: you did not get the video because you may not configured the base.bit properly follow the instructions in the link to configure it. https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Design-and-Debug-Techniques-Blog/Video-Series-23-Generate-a-video-output-on-Pynq-Z2-HDMI-out/ba-p/932553

Answer (score 0):

All of that looks good but rather than using the `tie` method, try reading each discrete frame from hdmi_in and writing the frame to hdmi_out, like so:

```
while True:
    try:
        frame = hdmi_in.readframe()
        hdmi_out.writeframe(frame)
        time.sleep(0.016)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

hdmi_in.close()
hdmi_out.close()
```